# Error in tunneling service on VMC

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

I've push an app to my CF on cloud_controller **paas.azure4j.us** with uri **yamashowcase.azure4j.us** .

When I tried to create tunnel on service which binded to it an error occured like this :

toriq@meruvian354:~$ sudo vmc tunnel yamashowcase-db

Stopping Application 'caldecott': OK

Redeploying tunnel application 'caldecott'.

Uploading Application:

Checking for available resources: OK

Packing application: OK

Uploading (1K): OK

Push Status: OK

Binding Service [yamashowcase-db]: OK

Staging Application 'caldecott': OK

Starting Application 'caldecott': OK

Getting tunnel connection info: ..........**Error: Expected remote tunnel to know about**

**yamashowcase-db, but it doesn't**

I use vmc version 0.3.23 . 
Any solution for this ??

Answer (score 1):

I think this error is a little misleading. I would check the logs on the instance, particularly the cloud controller log and log for the service node used for yamashowcase-db (mysql, postgre etc)

Comment: So where is the directory for the caldecott log files ??

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, all the log files are in /var/vcap/sys/log.

Comment: there is no log for caldecott inside of it ? any other solution ??

Comment: Hi, if this is still an issue it may be worth deleting the Caldecott application and then retry the tunnel again.